# Cut certain part of string after a specific character

Tags: php, string, substr, strstr

I am trying to basically cut a certain part of string after a specific character and then print it. I have this string and I need to cut the part after the last "/". Which means from this string:

```
$mystring = "https://example.com/node/some-article/diskuse828000";
```

I need to cut the part after the last "/" character, so it would return string looking like this:

```
$newstring = "https://example.com/node/some-article/
```

I have tried functions like substr and strstr, but I dont know how to cut the string after the specific last "/".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a function meant for paths:

```
$newstring = dirname($mystring);
```

Or you can find the position of the last `/` and extract up to it:

```
$newstring = substr($mystring, 0, strrpos($mystring, '/'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try explode();

```
explode("/",$mystring);
```

will split your string into an array based on the '/' char as follows.

```
Array=https:, ,example.com,node,some-article,diskuse828000
```

Then, you can just dump the last member of that array

Comment: That does work, but the best solution is that AbraCadaver suggested. Thank you anyways!

Comment: No worries. Thanks for the upvote.